# Is there a difference between multiple times loss.backward() and loss.backward() after multiplying loss by n in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, loss

Is there a difference between these two codes?

1

```
Loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
Loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
Loss.backward()
optimizer.step
```

2

```
Loss = 3 * Loss
Loss.backward()
optimizer.step
```

When I checked the gradient of the parameter after the last backward(), there was no difference between the two codes. However, there is a little difference in test accuracy after training.

I know this is not a common case, but it is related to the research I'm doing.

Comment: Theoretically there shouldn't be a difference. Due to limited floating point precision however there can occur small differences in terms of the gradients (especially if your network is very deep). So for both performance and numerical stability you should prefer option 2. Obviously option 1 backtracks three times as often through the graph as option 2 and hence will take three times longer to do so.

Comment: to test if it's due to the floating-point precision, u can run the inference twice for snippet 2 (or 1), see if the test accuracy for these two runs are also different.

Answer (score 0):

In option 1, every time you call `.backward()`, gradients are computed. After 3 calls, when you perform `optimizer.step`, the gradients are added and then weights are updated accordingly.

In option 2, you multiply the loss with a constant, so the gradients will be multiplied with that constant too.

So, adding a gradient value 3 times and multiplying the gradient value by 3 would result in the same parameter update.

Please note, I assume there is no loss due to floating point precision (as noted in the comments).

Answer (score -1):

To me, it looks very different.

Computing the loss three time won't do anything (first code snippet). You just hold on to the gradient you have previously calculated. (Check on your leaf tensors the value of the .grad() attribute).

However, the second code snippet with just multiply the gradients by three, thus speeding up Gradient Descent. For a standard Gradient descent optimizer, it would be like mutliplying the learning rate by 3.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Every time `backward` is called, it adds to the existing saved gradient (until `zero_grad` is called to zero it out).